# Chrome extension: pass variables from popup html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a very simple extension for chrome but i am stuck on passing a variable from popup html.

This is the code i have so far:

---

Manifest:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "img/test.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Auto Clicker"
   },
   "description": "Auto click",

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Auto Clicker",
   "permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
   "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

---

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {

             case  "popup-click-1":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab

                file: "myscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;

        }
    }
);
```

---

myscript.js

```
function foo(){
    document.getElementById('submit-button').click();
}

setInterval(function(){
    foo()}, 20000)

foo();
```

---

popup.js

```
 function clickHandler(e) {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click-1"}, function(response) {
            this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
        });
    }


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

    })
```

---

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
 <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
test

<form>
<input id="1" type = "text">
</br>
</form>
<button id='submit'> etst </button>
</body>
</html>
```

---

So far i run foo() when you click the submit button, which runs every 20sec.
What i want to achieve is add a number at the popup html and then use that number at myscript.js to set the time of setInterval function.

So here is a case scenario:

I open the page, i hit the extension button. There is a popup with a form. I put 30000 and then hit the sumbit. That way, foo() will run every 30sec.

Comment: 1. It's not clear what the problem is. 2. I don't see the need for background script in this case (actually I doubt your scheme works at all)

Comment: @wOxxOm 1) I want to get the variable that the user enters at the popup.html form and replace the number 20000 with that number, at myscript.js

2) The code works perfectly, i tried it so many times. When you hit the submit button on popup.html, the #submit-button gets clicked every 20sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the background script.

Inject the script in `popup.js` and pass the value:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "var timeout=" + document.getElementById('1').value,
        allFrames: true
    }, function(result) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "myscript.js", allFrames: true}, function(result) {
        });
    });
}
```

`myscript.js` will use the injected `timeout` variable:

```
.............
setInterval(foo, timeout);
.............
```

Comment: Okey, i tried so many time so far, and your code works perfeclty when i use the following as code: 

code: "var timeout = 1;"

then i go at myscript.js and use an alert(timeout) and get the value [1].
the problem is that it doesnt work when i use the document.getElementById .... Any ideas? 

P.S: i am still searching and testing though, i will update if i have more info

Edit: You are the best.Your code works 100%. It turns out that the input(at popup.html) had no id.

Comment: Use [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) to check the actual values of variables and expressions